# Error 5214 only when trying to add a Web Part Page from "More Options"

Tags: error, sql

I can add anything else, new site, new library, etc.

When I try to add a new webpart page I get an error.

Event log is 5214 insufficient SQL permissions.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_GetProductVersions', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.

I have tried to no avail:

Open Management Studio. Expand config database (default SharePoint_Config) -> Programmability -> Stored Procedure -> dbo.proc_GetProductVersions. Open Properties, open Permissions tab, click "Search" button. In opened menu click "Browse", and select WSS_Content_Application_Pools and grand this database role "Execute" rights

I'm assuming I just check the "Grant" box and click ok.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

its not related to sharepoint, well kinda ;).

In the error its telling you exactly the issue at hand! You dont have the execute permission ;) .

So you need to goto your server where the sql database is stored. Then go through the stored procedures that are stord in the databse. You should be looking for:

proc_GetProductVersions

It looks like your in the right place as you have done the right thing but looks like you havent added the correct account.

so in permissions, select add (to add user), click browse select the correct user as you have done just not WSS_Content_Application_Pools. Really you should have a custom user that you create that you give read or write permission and then add them in with execute  permission.

to add a user you need to goto the object exploorer and select the root node in the tree. right click and select properties then permissions. Here you can add the user :) . once that is done you can then do what you did but instead add that user with the execute permissions!

hope it helps :)